# Passing date type variable as method parameter in java

Tags: java, mysql

This is in the Main class

```
    Contest c = new Contest();
    c.setAnnouncementDate("2014-03-02");
    Contest.addContest(c);
```

I am trying to insert this date in my mysql table. But it gives type incompatibility.

So we tried this code:

```
    Contest c = new Contest();
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    java.sql.Date da = new java.sql.Date(f.parse("2014-04-02").getTime());
    c.setAnnouncementDate(da);
    Contest.addContest(c);
```

there is a addContest(Contest cont) method in Contest class which is used to insert the dates in mysql table:
code used is:

```
    PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement("Insert into " + TABLENAME + " ( " +       CONTESTID + " , " + ANNOUNCEMENTDATE + " , " + RESULTDECLARATIONDATE + " , " + SUBMISSIONSTARTDATE + " , " + SUBMISSIONENDDATE + " , " + REWARD + " ) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

we inserted date using :

```
    s.setDate(2, (java.sql.Date) cont.getAnnouncementDate());
```

here, it always inserts 2014-01-02 date in mysql table, irrespective of our argument that we pass.
please help me.

Comment: use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")` **(MM : months and mm : minutes)**

Comment: @AnkitLamba is right, but I think OP is saying that that specific date is getting inserted into the table even when he passes other dates in as parameters.. If so, and if the second block of code you've posted here is what's actually in your method, then it's because that's what you're telling it to do: `java.sql.Date da = new java.sql.Date(f.parse("2014-04-02").getTime());` Instead of `f.parse("2014-04-02")`, use `f.parse(nameOfYourParameter)`